# SKSpriteNode width increases with variable but won't decrease?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, progress

I have set up an SKSpriteNode as a progress/health bar. 
The width is set to a variable. 
This variable decreases with a timer however the width of the node doesn't decrease with it?
If I set the variable to increase then the node width increases no problem however doesn't work if I set the variable to decrease.
I fear I'm making a simple error here.
Here is the code that works, but doesn't work if I change += to -=

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var health = SKSpriteNode()
var healthTimer = Timer()
var progressValue = 350


func startHealthTimer() {

    progressValue += 20

}


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    healthTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startHealthTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    let healthTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "health.png")
    health = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: progressValue, height: 30))
    health.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2 + healthTexture.size().width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    health.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(health)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each update you are adding a new sprite without removing the old one. After time, you have a number of sprites on top of each other. The new sprites will be shorter, but the old ones are still showing, so the bar does not appear to get shorter.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var health: SKSpriteNode?
    var healthTimer = Timer()
    var progressValue = 350

    func startHealthTimer() {
        progressValue += 20
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        healthTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.startHealthTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if let health = self.health {
            health.removeFromParent()
        }

        let healthTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "health.png")
        self.health = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width: progressValue, height: 30))
        self.health.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2 + healthTexture.size().width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
        self.health.zPosition = 2
        self.addChild(self.health)
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand. How would I remove each sprite in place for the new one?

Comment: Call `removeFromParent` on the old one.

Comment: Great that does the job! Is there a way to have the width reduce off the right edge as opposed to equally off either edge of the node?

Comment: The position you are setting is the centre of the sprite, so calculate where the centre should be for keeping the left edge stay in the same spot.